# I had error msg while configuring selenium server standalone in eclipse

Tags: selenium

while configuring selenium standalone server  in eclipse, i got error as "could not find or load main class selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar". Could u please tell me what is the issue? And how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think your selenium standalone JAR not downloaded properly OR you have not imported selenium main jar before.